# Compare elements from two xml documents based on element value in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, join, element

I am trying to Join two XML based on the same elements, but my code doesn't return anything. The var result is empty. Can someone please help to sovle the problem? Many thanks in advance!

file one:

```
<bookstore>
   <book>
     <bookID>100</bookID>
     <name> The cat in the hat </name>
   </book>
   <book>
    <bookID>90</bookID>
    <name> another book </name>
   </book>
   <book>
      <bookID>103</bookID>
      <name> a new book </name>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

file two

```
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <bookID>100</bookID>
    <content> story </content>
  </book>
  <book>
    <bookID>90</bookID>
    <content> fiction </content>
  </book>
  <book>
    <bookID>103</bookID>
    <content> bio </content>
  </book>
 </bookstore>
```

the result I'm looking for is something like:

```
<result>
    <bookInfo>
       <bookID>103</bookID>
       <name> a new book </name>
       <content> bio </content>
    <bookInfo>
 </result>
```

The (wrong) code I am currently using is:

```
var reslut =    
                from a in fileone.Descendants("bookstore")
                join b in filetwo.Descendants("bookstore")

            on (string)fileone.Descendants("bookID").First() equals (string)filetwo.Descendants(""bookID"").First() 
            select new XElement("bookInfo", a, b);
```

Comment: I also tried to compare bookstore.Element("bookID") but that returns an empty file as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to join `<book>` elements on `<bookID>` child value, and then return`<bookInfo>` elements containing `bookID`, `name`, and `content` elements :

```
var bookInfos =
        from a in fileone.Descendants("book")
        join b in filetwo.Descendants("book")
            on (string)a.Element("bookID") equals (string)b.Element("bookID")
        select new XElement("bookInfo", 
                                a.Element("bookID"), 
                                a.Element("name"), 
                                b.Element("content")
                            );
var result = new XElement("result", bookInfos);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

**<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x1mu5g)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<result>
  <bookInfo>
    <bookID>100</bookID>
    <name> The cat in the hat </name>
    <content> story </content>
  </bookInfo>
  <bookInfo>
    <bookID>90</bookID>
    <name> another book </name>
    <content> fiction </content>
  </bookInfo>
  <bookInfo>
    <bookID>103</bookID>
    <name> a new book </name>
    <content> bio </content>
  </bookInfo>
</result>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But what shall I do if I want to keep the rest of the item values in fileone, without specifying the element "content"? I mean there might be other elements such as <description>...etc in fileone

Comment: You can say : `select new XElement("bookInfo", a.Element("name"),  b.Elements())`. That will take only `name` element from the first XML, and all elements (bookID, content, etc.) from the 2nd