# How to use xpath in Linq to check elements and attributes

Tags: c#, xml, linq, join, xpath

I'm trying to join two XML file, the join key sometimes come as element but sometimes come as attribute, as in the XML files below. How can I use XPath or || operator to solve the problem? Any other solutions are very much appreciated as well. Many thanks in advance!

file one:

```
<bookstore>
   <book>
     <bookID>100</bookID>
     <name> The cat in the hat </name>
   </book>
   <book>
     <bookID>90</bookID>
     <name> another book </name>
   </book>
   <book>
     <bookID>103</bookID>
     <name> a new book </name>
   </book>
</bookstore>
```

file two, in here the join key bookID is attribute:

```
 <bookstore>
  <book bookID=100>
    <content> story </content>
  </book>
  <book bookID=90>
    <content> fiction </content>
  </book>
  <book bookID=103>
    <content> bio </content>
  </book>
```

The result I'd like to have is

```
<result>
<bookInfo>
   <bookID>103</bookID>
   <name> a new book </name>
   <content> bio </content>
<bookInfo>
</result>
```

My current join operation based on this question [Compare elements from two xml documents based on element value in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900686/compare-elements-from-two-xml-documents-based-on-element-value-in-c-sharp)

```
    var bookInfos =
          from a in fileone.Descendants("book")
          join b in filetwo.Descendants("book")
              on (string)a.Element("bookID") equals  (string)b.Element("bookID") //how can I change the Join condition as the key might attributes in any of the two files? 
    select new XElement("bookInfo", 
                            a.Element("bookID"), 
                            a.Element("name"), 
                            b.Element("content")
                        );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can express your logic for retrieving element or attribute in the join condition:

```
var bookInfos =
    from a in fileone.Descendants("book")
    let aBookID = (string)a.Element("bookID") ?? (string)a.Attribute("bookID")
    join b in filetwo.Descendants("book")
        on aBookID equals (string)b.Element("bookID") ?? (string)b.Attribute("bookID")
    select new XElement("bookInfo",
        aBookID,
        a.Element("name"),
        b.Element("content")
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [null coalescing operator `??`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to check first for the presence of an attribute named `"bookID"`, and if not present, then an element of that name:

```
        var bookInfos =
              from a in fileone.Descendants("book")
              join b in filetwo.Descendants("book")
                  on ((string)a.Attribute("bookID") ?? (string)a.Element("bookID")) equals ((string)b.Attribute("bookID") ?? (string)b.Element("bookID"))
              select new XElement("bookInfo",
                                      new XElement("bookID", (string)a.Attribute("bookID") ?? (string)a.Element("bookID")),
                                      a.Element("name"),
                                      b.Element("content")
                                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
on (string)a.Element("bookID") equals (string)(b.Attribute("bookID"))
```

See [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CVX7rY)